# Static Google Map in XML

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am having a problem when I check syntax of an xml document I am creating. I have been trying to put a link to a static Google Map with parameters. However when I check the syntax it gives me the following error:
"XML Parsing error at line 191: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Here is the line

```
<venue_location>http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=90,0&zoom=16&size=512x512&maptype=hybrid&&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C90,0&sensor=false</venue_location>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` means "Start of entity" in XML. You can't just drop it in as data.

Represent it as `&amp;` or use a CDATA block.

If you are creating this XML programatically, then use a proper XML library and don't mash strings together.